# DataSet / DataTables with XSD Schema produces wrongly sequenced files

Tags: xml, xsd, dataset

I'm trying to get a dataset with tables written to a validated XML by means of an XSD Schema.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
ds.ReadXmlSchema("myschema.xsd");

//<some data filling>

ds.WriteXml("output.xml");
```

The output file looks okay, but on closer inspection I found out it won't validate because ds.WriteXml apparently first writes ALL the non-complex types, and after that the complex Types. (Which are in fact DataTables in the Dataset)

The Output file currently generates (Simplified for clarity):

```
<Main>
    <Element_A>Value_A</Element_A>
    <Element_B>Value_B></Element_B>
    <Complex_Type_1>.... </Complex_Type_1>
</Main>
```

Where in fact it should have generated:

```
<Main>
    <Element_A>Value_A</Element_A>
    <Complex_Type_1>.... </Complex_Type_1>
    <Element_B>Value_B></Element_B>
</Main>
```

Is there any way to influence the order of which the sub elements are written?

The (again, greatly simplified) XSD file I'm using clearly states the elements in the right sequence :

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Main">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Element_A">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Complex_Type_1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                                    .......
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Element_B" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:maxLength value="35"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```